# Builder c++ TButton problems?

Tags: c++builder

I'm using Builder C++ 6.

in the folowing code I want my function `KreirajPOlja()` to generate random AnsiString characters on the buttons but what i always gain is just matrix 9*9 with just one generated character as in the picture:

[image]

```
void __fastcall TForm1::KreirajPolja()
{
                  int tr;

       for(int i=0;i<dim_x;i++)

       for(int j=0;j<dim_y;j++)  {


  Dugme[i][j]->Height=20;
  Dugme[i][j]->Width=Dugme[i][j]->Height;
  Dugme[i][j]->Left=i*Dugme[i][j]->Height;
  Dugme[i][j]->Top=j*Dugme[i][j]->Height;
  Dugme[i][j]->Parent=this;
              tr=PostaviRandom();
  Dugme[i][j]->Caption= NizSlova[tr];



}


    Button1->Caption="submit";
    Button1->Enabled=false;




  Form1->Width=dim_x* 20+5;
   Form1->Height=(dim_y+2)* 20+25;

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------


                 int __fastcall TForm1::PostaviRandom(){
                        int k;
                     srand(time(0));
                     k=rand()%sizeof(NizSlova);

                 return k;}
```

and here is the folowing cpp code

```
        #ifndef Unit1H
        #define Unit1H
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
     #include <Classes.hpp>


        #include <Controls.hpp>

       #include <StdCtrls.hpp>

        #include <Forms.hpp>

         #include <time.h>

       //--- ------------------------------------------------------------------------

              class TForm1 : public TForm
               {

            __published:    // IDE-managed Components

        TButton *Button1;

       void __fastcall FormCreate(TObject *Sender);

        public:     // User declarations

          TButton*** Dugme;
            TImage *** Slike;
         TEdit *brojac;
       int dim_x, dim_y;
       int vrijeme,kr;
       int BrojSlova, br;
       AnsiString NizSlova;


    __fastcall TForm1(TComponent* Owner);
    void __fastcall KreirajSlova();
    void __fastcall AlocirajProstor();
    void __fastcall BrisiProstor();
    void __fastcall AlocirajProstorZaSlova();
    void __fastcall BrisiProstorZaSlova();


    void __fastcall KreirajPolja();
    virtual   int __fastcall PostaviRandom();
    AnsiString __fastcall DajSlovo();



       };
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        extern PACKAGE TForm1 *Form1;
          //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
             #endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't call `srand` in your loop. Call it once at the start of the program.

Each time you call `srand` you reset the random number generator. Since you call it with the same parameter each time (your code runs in less than a second so the value of `time(NULL)` doesn't change), you get the same result from `rand()`.

There is no need to call `srand` multiple times in the same program unless you intentionally want to reproduce an old sequence of random numbers.